# internal DNS server limiting the speed as 55kb/sec?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

1. We have LAN internal DNS server ( 192.168.205.200 )
2. DNS server Running on my additional Domain Controller
3. Tested with nslookup, ipaddress and hostname resolving without any error
4. DHCP server Running on 3750 Switch ( Checked with Cisco confirmed the configuration )
5. DNS name server pointed to 192.168.205.200

ISSUE :

1. Host getting ipaddress and DNS from DHCP server .Maximum file transfer Bandwidth 55KB/sec.
2. Assigned Static DNS on Host as ISP DNSServer Address, host getting full bandwidth which is 1mb/sec.

Comment: What default gateway do you get when using the DHCP server and what default gateway are you using when configuring statically?

Comment: Default getaway i am getting from DHCP server .I a mnot configure any static IPaddress and gateway , .Only i will assign the static DNS Address . All others are same as DHCP server .

Comment: If the issue is solved then please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

DNS is about creating a link from an alphabetical name (FQDN) to a numeric (IP). No more, no less. It therefore has no influence on bandwidth if you connect to the same host.

Comment: I Added the ISP DNS server IPAddress on DNS properties /forward zones ,Now work like a charm ..we are enjoying the 15mbps/sec bandwidth .   ~~~~ ISSUE SOLVED  ~~~ Thanks to all  by Me.K~